# Magento : How to change USPS shipping titles?

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7, usps

For example, I want to change `First-Class Mail International Large Envelope` to say `First-Class Mail International Large Envelope (tracking not available)`

I have read a few different methods online about how to do this, and none of them work for me. I can pay if someone provides an answer that works!

I am using `Magento version 1.7.0.2` and also using the `OneStepCheckout` module, if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Shipping module's titles can be edited in the corresponding module's `etc/system.xml`. Search `First-Class Mail International Large Envelopebe` in it and change it as you like.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not finding any etc/system.xml under a USPS folder. Is there somewhere specific I should be looking?

Comment: look USPS module folder inside `app/code/local/` or `app/code/community/` folders It should have an `etc/` inside

Comment: Nope those directories contain other modules I added... USPS isn't a module, it's a shipping option built into Magento, you know that right? I just want to make sure we are talking about the same thing

Comment: Have you tried changing `Title` in that Module via backend? `System>config>shippingmethods>USPS` ?

Comment: Yes I can change the name of the Title, but I want to change the names of the "allowed methods"

Comment: I hope you can change it in `app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/config.xml` in line number 197. Search for the names you need to change. I didnt tested it full. So do care when you change. Copy the files to local and do the changes or create a custom module if you knows..

Comment: Ok cool, so I did that. After doing that I had to go in the backend and select that method as an "allowed method". However, after I do that, it doesn't show up at checkout. If I change it back to the original name, it shows up again at checkout. Any ideas?